# How to calculate E(X|X+Y=a) for some given a?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X \sim exp(\lambda_1)$ and $Y\sim exp(\lambda_2)$. Than how to calculate 
$E(X | X+Y=a)$ for a given $a>0$.

My try: 
$E(X | X+Y=a)=\int_0^\infty xP(X| X=a-Y)dx$
Then how to calculate  $P(X | X=a-Y)$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. $X \le x$ is an event, not a variable. Do you mean $P$ instead of $E$?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein. You are right. This was a mistake I edited it.Thanks.

Comment: $E(X | X=a-y) = a-y$.  You probably want $0 \le y \le a $

Comment: @Henry. I am not sure. Is it true?

Comment: @janak Yes, it is true.  $a-y$ is the expected value of $X$ when given that $X=a-y$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes it is true. I get it. But I think I am in a wrong way to prove it. I edit it.

Comment: The question is not answerable without using the proper tools and the proper rigorous definitions (and some comments above do not help, I am afraid): one asks for $u(a)$ where the function $u$ satisfies $E(X|X+Y)=u(X+Y)$. How is $E(X|X+Y)$ defined, already?

Comment: @janak are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Mehdi It doesn't actually matter. Whether or not they are, $X$ is *conditionally* dependent on $Y$ when given $X+Y=a\;$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Mehdi..There is no assumption of independency of X and Y.

Comment: @Mehdi Sorry, you are right. It does matter.

Comment: @janak Next time, please do not accept an answer before you checked it and understand it.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for coming back to me with this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you were on the right track, using the Law of Iterated Expectation.

For some condition $\mathcal A$,  the LIE is:
$\mathsf E_X(X\mid \mathcal A) = \mathsf E_Y(\mathsf E_{X\mid Y}(X\mid \mathcal A, Y)\mid \mathcal A)$

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X\mid X+Y=a) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid X=a-Y, Y)\mid X+Y=a)
\\ & = \int_0^a \mathsf E(X\mid X=a-y, Y=y)\;f_Y(y\mid X+Y=a)\operatorname d y
\\ & = \int_0^a (a-y) f_{Y}(y\mid X+Y=a)\operatorname dy
\\ & = \frac{\int_0^a(a-y)\;f_{X,Y}(a-y,y) \operatorname d y}{\int_0^a f_{X,Y}(a-t,t)\operatorname dt}
\\ & = a-\frac{\int_0^a y\;f_{X,Y}(a-y,y) \operatorname d y}{\int_0^a f_{X,Y}(a-t,t)\operatorname dt}
\end{align}$$

Now, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X\mid X+Y=a)
 & = \frac{\int_0^a \lambda_1\lambda_2 (a-y)\;e^{-\lambda_1(a-y)}e^{-\lambda_2 y} \operatorname d y}{\int_0^a \lambda_1\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_1(a-t)}e^{-\lambda_2 t}\operatorname dt}
\\[2ex]
 & = \frac{\int_0^a (a-y)\;e^{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)y} \operatorname d y}{\int_0^a  e^{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)t}\operatorname dt}
\\[2ex]
 & =\begin{cases} a-\dfrac{1+(a(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)-1)e^{a(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(e^{a(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}-1)} & \mbox{if }\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2
\\[1ex] a/2 & \mbox{if }\lambda_1=\lambda_2\end{cases}
\\[2ex] & =\begin{cases} \dfrac 1{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}-\dfrac{a}{e^{a(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}-1} & \mbox{if }\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2
\\[1ex] a/2 & \mbox{if }\lambda_1=\lambda_2\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thus the answer does not depend on the distribution of X? Amusing...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But it is surprising to note that the answer does not depends on distribution of X, as Did points out.

Comment: Hi Graham. I think perhaps $f_Y(y)$ should instead be $f_{Y|Z}(y|a)$ if we let $Z=X+Y$: $\quad E(X|Z=a)=E(E(X|Z=a)|Y)=\int_{0}^{a}{E(X|Z=a\cap Y=y)\;P(Y=y|Z=a)\;dy} = \int_{0}^{a}{E(X|X=a-y)\;f_{Y|Z}(y|a)\;dy} = \int_{0}^{a}{(a-y)\;f_{Y|Z}(y|a)\;dy}.$

Comment: Hmmm, in the case $Y=X$, we have $E(X|2X=a)$ which should be $a/2$ but I don't think your answer gives that.

Comment: Mmmm... point.  ...

Comment: Shouldn't the integration be $\int_0^\infty \cdots$? That way, you get the answer $a-E(Y)$ (which makes intuitive sense) and in the case @MickA speaks of, the middle line is $\int_0^\infty a/2 f_X(x)dx=a/2$ which also makes more sense. But I'll be the first to admit I'm a little rusty...

Comment: @hejseb My thoughts: upper limit $a$ is correct because $X$ can't be negative ($X,Y$ have exponential distribution): $a$ is the largest value $Y$ can take. Also, answer $a-E(Y)$ is negative when $a\lt E(Y)=1/\lambda_2$ which makes no sense since $X\gt 0$.

Comment: @MickA Thank you.  I spotted my error.

Comment: No problem. Our final results look different but are in fact the same. :-) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z=X+Y.\;$ I'll assume independence of $X,Y$, otherwise we don't have enough information for a solution. Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X\mid Z=a) &=& E(E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Z=a) \\
&=& \int_0^a{E(X\mid Y=y\cap Z=a) f_{Y|Z}(y|a)\;dy} \\
&=& \int_0^a{E(X\mid X=a-y\cap Y=y) f_{Y|Z}(y|a)\;dy} \\
&=& \int_0^a{(a-y) f_{Y|Z}(y|a)\;dy}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now,

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{Y|Z}(y|z) &=& \dfrac{f_{Y,Z}(y,z)}{f_{Z}(z)} \\
&=& \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(z-y,y)}{f_{Z}(z)} \\
&=& \dfrac{f_{X}(z-y)f_{Y}(y)}{f_{Z}(z)} \qquad\qquad\text{by independence of $X,Y$.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Two cases: (a) $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, and (b) $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

(a) $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z(z) &=& \int_0^z{P(X=z-y)P(Y=y)\;dy} \\
&=& \int_0^z{f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\;dy} \\
&=& \int_0^z{\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 (z-y)} \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 y}\;dy} \\
&=& \int_0^z{\lambda_1^2 e^{-\lambda_1 z}\;dy} \\
&=& \lambda_1^2 z e^{-\lambda_1 z} \\
&& \\
\therefore f_{Y|Z}(y|z) &=& \dfrac{\lambda_1^2 e^{-\lambda_1 z}}{\lambda_1^2 z e^{-\lambda_1 z}} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{z}
&& \\
\therefore E(X\mid Z=a) &=& \int_0^a{\frac{a-y}{a}\;dy} \\
&=& \left[ y - \dfrac{y}{2a^2} \right]_0^a \\
&=& a - \dfrac{a}{2a^2} = \dfrac{a}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

This is what you might expect for the case $X,Y$ i.i.d.

(b) $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$

This case is solved by similar procedure though the working is a little more tedious than for case (a). We get the result that

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X\mid Z=a) &=& \dfrac{\frac{1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} e^{-\lambda_2 a} - \left(a + \frac{1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \right) e^{-\lambda_1 a}}{e^{-\lambda_2 a} - e^{-\lambda_1 a}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

As a sanity check, when $\lambda_1 \ll \lambda_2$ we expect this value to be close to, but below, $a$: here $e^{-\lambda_1 a}$ dominates $e^{-\lambda_2 a}$ so $E(X\mid Z=a) \approx a + \frac{1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}$.

Also, when $\lambda_1 \gg \lambda_2$ we expect this value to be close to, but above, $0$: here $e^{-\lambda_2 a}$ dominates $e^{-\lambda_1 a}$ so $E(X\mid Z=a) \approx \frac{1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for pointing out the important flaw in the previous answer which also helps to correct the previous answer. Could you please clarify this two point. First, In right side of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th line of the first equation array you have written $f_{X|Z}(y|a)$, should it not be $f_{Y|Z}(y|a)$? Second, also it is not clear for me how (in the first line) $X=E(X|Y,Z)$. Please explain.

Comment: @janak Thanks, I fixed those mistakes. First line doesn't mean $X=E(X|Y,Z)$. The inner expectation $E(X|Y,Z)$ is expectation over $X$ and outer expectation $E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z=a)$ is over $Y$. This line is really just [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) but instead of having a simple r.v. $X$, we have $X|Z$. The expansion on line 2 is really what it means. I don't like notation such as $E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z=a)$ because it's confusing, but that's what is standard. Note that $E(X|Y,Z)$ is a function of $Y$ and $Z$: when $Y=y$ and $Z=z$, this function takes real value $E(X|Y=y,Z=z)$.

Comment: One more point: Is $f_Z(z)$ is density function or CDF? The derivation of $f_Z(z)$ suggest that it is CDF (since integral from 0 to $z$).

Comment: @janak $f_Z(z)$ is the density function. The integral used to derive it, you can think of as all the ways you can have $X$ and $Y$ so that $X+Y=z$ (to borrow from the discrete case).

Comment: I got it. Thanks for such nice explanation.